# Using sed and mv to add characters to files

Tags: sed, mv

First off, I'd like to say that I know this is almost an exact duplicate of some posts that I've read, but have not had any luck with referencing.

I have 100+ files that all follow a very strict naming convention of `5_##_<name>.ext` My issue was that when originally making these files I failed to realise that `5_100_` and above would mess up my ordering.

I am now trying to append a 0 in front of every number between 01 and 99. I've written a bash script using sed that works for the file contents (the file name is in the file as well):

```
#!/bin/bash
for fl in *.tcl; do

    echo Filename: $fl

    #sed -i 's/5_\(..\)_/5_0\1_/g' $fl

done
```

However, this only changes the contents and not the filename itself. I've read that mv is the solution (`rename` is simpler but I do not have it on my system). My current incarnation of my multiple attempts is:

`mv "$fl" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/5_\(..\)_/5_0\1_/g')` but it gives me an error: `mv: missing destination file operand after <filename>`

Again, I'm sorry about the duplicate but I wasn't able to solve my issue by reading it. I'm sure I'm just using the combination of `mv` and `sed` incorrectly.

---

Solution was entered in the comments. I was using $file instead of $fl.

Comment: Try `echo "$fl"` instead of `echo "$file"` in the `mv` command.

Comment: I am literally the worst. Thank you. If you'd leave this comment as an answer I'd love to choose it and close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be useful:

```
for n in $(seq 99)
do
  prefix2="5_$(printf "%02d" ${n})_"
  prefix3="5_$(printf "%03d" ${n})_"

  for f in ${prefix2}*.tcl
  do
    suffix="${f#${prefix2}}"

    [[ -r "${prefix3}${suffix}" ]] || mv "${prefix2}${suffix}" "${prefix3}${suffix}"

  done
done
```

Rather than processing every single file, it only looks at the ones that currently have a "5_XX_" prefix, and only renames them if the corresponding "5_XXX_" file doesn't already exist...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for fl in *.tcl
 do
    NewName="$(echo "${fl} | sed '/^5_[0-9]\{2\}_/ s/../&0/' )"
    #echo "Filename: ${fl} -> ${NewName}

    [ ! "${fl}" = "${NewName}" ] && mv ${fl} ${NewName}
done
```

- With a bit a securisation a allow to pass several time on same folder (changing only needed one).
- Under linux (non posix sed by default), use `sed --posix` instead of simple sed call